# Dropdown Population with Jquery Ajax & CFC

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, coldfusion, cfc

I'm trying to populate a HTML dropdown with database data. To do so, I'm retrieving data from database and creating option elements as below:

```
var obj = eval("(" + data + ")");
for (i = 1; i <= obj.DATA.length; i++) {
    var col_val = obj.DATA[i - 1];
    $("#dropdown").append('<option value="' + col_val + '">' + col_val + '</option>');
}
```

I tried an alternate method also as below:

```
$("#dropdown").html(data);
```

where, data is a string containing a list of option elements returned by the called CFC page after looping over the database query using cfloop.

Before adding the new options, I'm removing the older ones using either of the below statements.

```
$('#dropdown').empty(); 

$('#dropdown option').remove();

$('#dropdown').html('');
```

After analysis, I found that removing options is causing the maximum delay.

Is there any faster alternate JavaScript or Jquery function that can be used for removing options? OR Do you suggest any work-around to improve the performance?

Note: I have to use ColdFusion & AJAX for this purpose. Also I can't use the Built-in AJAX Functionality of ColdFusion.

Thanks!!

Comment: Any reason you're using JavaScript to populate this client-side vs. pre-generating it server-side with ColdFusion?

Comment: First: I don't have to refresh the page irrespective of  client-side or server-side technology. Please let me know if the same can be done with server-side technology,i.e., ColdFusion.

Comment: Second: Built-in AJAX functionality of ColdFusion isn't an option in my case, e.g., cfajaximport, etc.

Comment: I can't see how a simple loop can be slow.  Do you mean the ajax response is slow?  Looping a few items and adding to a select combo should be practically instant.

Comment: There are a minimum number of 4000-5000 rows returned by database query. Hence, the delay is most probably caused by the number of option elements that it has to create dynamically. Do you suggest any other alternative to display & use this data.

Answer (score 1):

I usually return html from the ajax request so the response looks like

```
<option value = "1">1</option>
<option value = "2">2</option>
<option value = "3">3</option>
<option value = "4">4</option>
...
```

then just use `$("#selectName").html(data);` to populate the select with the response which now contains a bunch of option tags.

Comment: Thanks Travis!! I tried this option but there is hardly any improvement in the performance. There are a minimum number of 4000-5000 rows returned by database query. Hence, the delay is mostly probably caused by the number of option elements that it has to add dynamically. Do you suggest any other alternative to display & use this data?

Comment: have you timed your query and the amount of time it takes to output 4-5k records? you can put getTickCount() before the query and after the output and subtract the difference. you can also use chrome developer tools or firebug to look at the request and see where exactly the delay is.

Comment: I tried doing so using the Date().getTime() of JavaScript. I put the start time immediately before the Ajax call and end time immediately after the call returns with the 'options' string. However, the time is much less compared to overall processing time. To be more clear, the query executes in avg. 6 secs. And the options are displayed after a whopping avg. of 16 secs.

Comment: I can't think of anything that might speed that up.  I imagine if you browsed directly to your requested response it would still take a few seconds to render 5k rows of data.

Comment: 5k results in a drop down seems kind of overwhelming anyway... is there any reason that many results are displayed? is there anyway to narrow the options down further?

Comment: Options can't be narrowed! However, the way its displayed can be changed. So can we use any other control to display & use it instead of 'select' element?

Comment: is the 6 second query pretty static?  you could cache it and use an auto-complete instead of a drop down.  wait for the user to enter 3 letters then start the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The ColdFusion is undefined error is probably because your virtual mapping to the /CFIDE/scripts folder is missing, you can either manually copy that into your webroot from a similar CF install to get around this or fix your installation.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your inputs!! I had tried this earlier and arrived at the same conclusion. But this option isn't available to me. So the Built-in AJAX functionality of ColdFusion can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping into the DOM on every iteration of the loop.
You need to do the $("#dropdown") operation after you exit the loop.

Comment: I tried implementing Travis's suggestion above. Here, the CFC page creates a string of <option> list & returns it to the calling CFM page. The CFM page then just adds it to the dropdown using below statement

'    $("#dropdown").html(options_list_string);

But here also there was no significant improvement in the performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are getting your options via ajax, you should be able to run firefox Firebug console and see the exact amount of time it takes to get the data. This would prove for sure whether the issue is download time vs rendering time. Also consider: query caching, writing the js array or list to a js file and using straight js over CF or reducing the number of options (i can't image scrolling through 5k options)
2. You could also try downloading the data as a list and using

   ```
   str.replace(',','<option>')
   ```

to "wrap" each list item in an option tag. Remember: you don't have to have the value parameter if the value and the text are the same. AND: you don't have to close the option tag:

```
    <option>1<option>2<option>3...<option>N
```

1. Finally, if this is still too slow, then I would suggest using a lazy loader to load your options in more manageable chunks. You could even trigger the lazy loader to keep loading chunks regardless of the users action (with settimeout).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alain for the Firebug suggestion!! I got to know that its the remove statement that is causing the delay. 

I tried `$('#dropdown').empty();` , `$('#dropdown option').remove();`
and `$('#dropdown').html('');`. However, none of them provides any improvement. 

Is there any alternate JavaScript or Jquery function that can be used? OR Do you suggest any work-around to improve the performance?

Comment: Try lazy loader or even just an ajax loader so the client is available as the list loads.

Comment: Can you give an example of the same in the context of loading dropdown options using ajax loader or lazy loader?

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax this may be helpful using Coldfusion only

```
<CFSELECT NAME="name"
    REQUIRED="Yes/No"
    MESSAGE="text"
    ONERROR="text"
    SIZE="integer"
    MULTIPLE="Yes/No"
    QUERY="queryname"
    SELECTED="column_value"
    VALUE="text"
    DISPLAY="text"
    PASSTHROUGH="HTML_attributes">

</CFSELECT>
```

near the query attribute you can pass your query name.